# Proving that a product of matrices cannot be expressed as a product of only 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

In what follows, $A\in \text{Mat}_{m,m}$, $B\in \text{Mat}_{m,n}$ and $C\in \text{Mat}_{n,n}$. I wonder if it is possible to disprove the following statement?

> For any $A$ and $C$, there exists a matrix $D$ (that depends on $A$ and $C$) such that $ABC=DB$ for every $B$.

Comment: In your case $DB$ is not defined - dimensions are off

Comment: Sorry $D$ should be an $m$ by $m$ matrix

Comment: Do you mean doesn't exist *in general*? Because for $m=n$ and $B=I$, such a matrix certainly exists: $D=AC$.

Comment: I mean can you find such a $D$ matrix such that $ABC=DB$ for all $B$.

Comment: @user112110 just to ensure we have the quantifiers right you are asking whether:

$\forall A,C \exists D \forall B (ABC=DB)$ given that $A,B,C,D$ are all matrices of the appropriate types.

Comment: Yes I mean exactly like that.

Answer (score 1):

One particular case: $m=n$, $A=I$. As the identity should hold for all matrices $B$, we can take $B=I$, as suggested by @pew, to obtain $D= C$. Now the problem reduces to whether $$\forall B\quad  BC= CB,$$
which is, in general case, false - not all matrices commute.